Ubuntu server 14.04.5 - sending emails on behalf of customer domain
Good day all,
I have a customer who has a website on a VM ubuntu server which is hosted by ioMart.
They have been having increased issues more specifically Gmail, when sending emails from the website on the VM server (domain1 = VM server). I am using postfix to help send the emails.
I have tried to add a SPF to the customers main DNS (domain2) which included domain1 and the ip4 address for domain1.
v=spf1 mx include:[domain1] include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:_spf.google.com ip4:nn.nn.nnn.nnn ~all
I have also tried to create a DKIM on the server, using OpenDKIM, however I suspect I may have created this incorrectly. I created it using Domain2 rather than Domain1. I do not have access to the DNS for Domain1, I would have to instruct ioMart to create entries (extra costings). [[[this probably answers my question]]]
With both the SPF and DKIM I had made in place, it would still fail when sending an email to gmail with the following error (mail.log on the server):
Your email has been blocked because the sender is unauthenticated. 550-5.7.26 Gmail requires all senders to authenticate with either SPF or DKIM. 550-5.7.26  550-5.7.26  Authentication results: 550-5.7.26  DKIM = did not pass 550-5.7.26  SPF [domain1] with ip: [nn.nn.nnn.nnn] = did 550-5.7.26 not pass 550-5.7.26  550-5.7.26  For instructions on setting up authentication
When sending an email to M365 - this does arrive but it has the following within the headers:
Authentication-Results: spf=none (sender IP is nn.nn.nnn.nnn)
 smtp.mailfrom=[domain1]; dkim=fail (invalid public key)
 header.d=[domain2];dmarc=none action=none
 header.from=[domain1];compauth=pass reason=105
Received-SPF: None (protection.outlook.com: [domain1]
 does not designate permitted sender hosts)
Received: from [domain1] (nn.nn.nnn.nnn) by
 DB5-----B9D.mail.protection.outlook.com (nn.nnn.n.nnn) with Microsoft
 SMTP Server id 15.20.7918.13 via Frontend Transport;

My question: Is there a way I can use [domain2] DNS to assist in allowing the emails to pass gmail authentication, or would I need to use [domain1] for this?

The sending mail server DKIM signing the message which you created DKIM public keys, in it's DNS, the domain it is sending on behalf of in it's DNS should have CNAME records for their DKIM pointing back to the sending email server's domain iirc. The out Internet NAT'd address of the sending mail server, should be added to the SPF record of the domain it is sending on behalf so that domains says, YES, that IP address is allowed to send as my domain, I approve this. The CNAME record pointing to the sending mail server domain should allow public signatures to pass.

When you are sending emails where email address is joe@example.com, the example.com domain should have relevant SPF and DKIM entries.
The DNS name of the mail server that does this operation is not directly relevant. You do need to include the DNS name of the email server in the SPF record, so that other email servers know which mail servers can send email for the domain.
The invalid public key error for DKIM could mean that you have entered the record incorrectly. Maybe the whole string is not there, or there are extra charcaters inside.
